# Bracket expansion, keeps failing tests.

Tags: algebra-precalculus, arithmetic

It's $((a + b)c - bc)a - a^2(c - a)$.

I rearrange to make it easier to see:

$a(c(a + b) - bc) - a^2(c - a)$

**Expand the term on the left**:

$a(ac + bc) - abc - a^2(c - a)$

**Again**:

$aac + abc - abc - a^2(c - a)$

Remove the like terms which cancel:

$aac - a^2(c - a)$

**Expand**:

$aac - a^2(c - a)$

$aac - a^2c + a^2a$

**Organise**:

$a^2c - 2ac + 2a^2$

But it looks like the game is already lost because this result already disagrees with some of the programs I'm using to check it.

In fact, Alpha claims it goes down to $
a^3$

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: can you correct your post please?

Comment: I was asked to remove the word difficult.... I did. What do you mean correct it?

Comment: You seem to have made the mistake of equating $a^2$ with $2a$ in more than one place.

Comment: Thank you! Yes! That will certainly have something to do with it. :-)

I haven't had a chance for another run through yet, but when I do, I'll return to see how it worked out.

Answer (score 2):

I think it should be $a^2$ instead of $a2$ in the problem. Then, your second to last line reads $aac - a^2c + a^2a = a^3$ as claimed by Wolfram alpha.

Comment: Yessssss.... you're right, I copied one of the terms down with an error and that's what threw me out from there after, thanks.

Answer (score 2):

we have $$((a+b)c-bc)a-a^2(c-a)=(ac+bc-bc)a-a^2c+a^3=a^2c-a^2c+a^3=a^3$$

Comment: Best answer in my view..... I think I may have just earned the rep to +1 you.... well done... and thanks.

Comment: you are welcome

Answer (score 0):

**hint**: $(a+b)c - bc = ac + bc - bc = ac$, and $a^2(c-a) = a^2c- a^3$